# ansible-galaxy and git clone from Bitbucket.org

Tags: git, ansible, bitbucket, ansible-galaxy

I am using ansible-galaxy (v2.0.0.2) to install ansible roles that which has the source code on Bitbucket through the requirements.yml file. But I could not checkout the code from bitbucket.org with the private key. Here is the error message, and also my `requirements.yml` content.

Does any one what's the correct `requirements.yml` file format for ansible-galaxy 2.0.0.2?

```
  + ansible-galaxy -vvv install --force --role-file ansible/requirements.yml --roles-path ./ansible/roles

    Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
    Opened /tmp/.ansible_galaxy
    found role {'scm': 'git', 'src': 'git@bitbucket.org:myrepo/nginx.git', 'version': 'latest', 'name': 'nginx'} in yaml file
    Installing role nginx 

     [WARNING]: - nginx was NOT installed successfully: - command git checkout
    latest failed in directory /tmp/tmpQRZc8j (rc=1)
    ERROR! - you can use --ignore-errors to skip failed roles and finish processing the list.
```

[requirements.yml]

```
- name: nginx
  src: git@bitbucket.org:myrepo/nginx.git
  scm: git
  version: latest
  accept_hostkey: yes
  key_file: /tmp/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the scp syntax does not work. The url one might:

```
ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myrepo/nginx.git
```

Try, as in [this ansible issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/8937#issuecomment-55097691):

> Direct copy from github clone repo path

```
git@github.com:geerlingguy/ansible-role-php.git
```

> Actual URL that works

```
ssh://git@github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-php.git
```

> You have to replace the `:` with a `/`.
>   And it needs to be a URL (i.e. contain `://`) otherwise ansible-galaxy assumes it's a filesystem path.

Comment: `[ERROR]: failed to download the file: <urlopen error unknown url type: ssh>`

Comment: @papanito Did you manage to make it work in your Ansible task?

Comment: Unfortunately not, tried different variations but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

try `git+ssh` schema

works on ansible-galaxy 2.7.8

`ansible-galaxy install git+ssh://bitbucket.org:<username>/<role-name>.git`

Comment: What about the ssh port number?  Ours doesn't run on port 22.

Comment: for instance sh "GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' ansible-galaxy install -f git+ssh://git@bitbucket.services.net:7999/project/ansible-roles -p ./"

Answer (score 2):

If you set "scm: git" underneath the src, galaxy will run "git clone XYZ" where XYZ is your src: field.  So, anything you can "git clone XYZ" is what you put in the src field.

```
- src: ssh://git@bitbucket.internal.com:8899/project/repo-name.git
  scm: git
```

For the private key, in case it's not your default ssh key, we use ssh-agent(1) (see manpage for usage).

Answer (score 0):

As said by Ansible, if you look in your `/tmp/tmpQRZc8j` directory you will see that your role has been fetch.

The problem is that you have specified a wrong version argument and ansible is trying to make a `git checkout latest` which is not possible (unless with a branch or tag named latest).

You have to give an existing branch or tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the unknown *key_file* and *accept_hostkey* attributes in your *requirements.yml* file.

According to the [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/galaxy/user_guide.html#installing-multiple-roles-from-a-file), the only available attributes for the *requirements.yml* file are:

- src
- scm
- version
- name

You will need to use the ssh *config* file to configure the ssh-key to use for your private repositories. Here are some helpful links:

- https://tecadmin.net/how-to-use-ssh-config-file/
- https://gist.github.com/gubatron/d96594d982c5043be6d4#gistcomment-3553682

Answer (score -1):

The error will be due to some wrong details given by you in requirements.yml it can be git URL, or version:number or version: branch name

Comment: Please change answer to denote the wrong details. Also, please indicate the sources that you have referred to.